# Filter customers without using subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, filtering

How can I find customers who didn't buy any books in the last 6 month without using subqueries.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email
FROM customers
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT customers.id
    FROM customers
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
    WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, orders.purchased_date, GETDATE()) < 6
    GROUP BY customers.id
);
```

Comment: So I just roughly checked the performance of this using the estimated execution plan against real tables I have with `499,290` clients and '1,333,326' orders. Your query took 43%, Johns query took 39% (a tiny improvement), my query took 9% (a massive improvement) and SMors query took 9% (again a massive improvement). So clearly performance is not your criteria here, which is why it would be really interesting to know why you are excluding the option of a sub-query?

Comment: Wow, i didn't think that. When i learn sql, instructor said that subqueries take so long. Take my example, when query executed, it goes twice in customers table, one for find all customers who bought int the last six month, then goes all customers and check if customer id is not there

Comment: Thats a lesson to learn about SQL Server... performance is not always easy to predict... one can only be sure about performance by measuring it. And specifically if you are interested in performance, you should ask for a highly performing query rather than assuming applying restrictions which may or may not make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option without a sub-query (not clear why) ... just brute force :)

```
Select C.first_name
      ,C.last_name
      ,C.email
      ,LastPurchase = max(O.purchased_date)
  From customers C
  Join orders    O on O.customer_id = C.customer_id 
  Group by C.customer_id
          ,C.first_name
          ,C.last_name
          ,C.email
  Having max(O.purchased_date) <= dateadd(month,-6,getdate())
```

Comment: Does that handle customers with no orders at all?

Comment: @DaleK How are you a customer if you have no orders ?

Comment: Technically you might not be :) but most customer databases I've seen have customers with no order for one reason or another.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a sub-query? Its the best tool for the job here. You can improve your query (while still using a sub-query) with `NOT EXISTS` rather than `IN` and by not applying the `DATEDIFF` function directly to your column, because that makes the query unsargable (i.e. can't use indexes). Also `DATEDIFF` counts month changes between then and now, not actual months. See logic change below.

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.customer_id = c.customers.id
    AND o.purchased_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
)
```

Table aliases are always recommended as well.

Assuming you asked this question from a performance perspective, I roughly checked the performance of this using the estimated execution plan against real tables I have with 499,290 clients and 1,333,326 orders. Your query took 43%, John's query took 39% (a tiny improvement), my query took 9% (a massive improvement) and SMor's query took 9% (again a massive improvement). So if performance is really what your question is about you should ask that and not artificially constrain the best performing solution.

Answer (score 2):

EXCEPT comes to mind as a kludge-y alternative. A cte gets all customer IDs and then removes those based on orders where the purchase date is WITHIN 6 months. You then just join the cte back to the customer table.

```
with cte as (
   select customer_id from dbo.customers
   except
   select customer_id from dbo.orders where purchase_date >= dateadd(month, -6, getdate())
)
select cust.customer_id, ... 
from dbo.customers as cust
inner join cte on cte.customer_id = cust.customer_id
order by ...;
```

Comment: A CTE *is* essentially a sub-query :) but really it depends on why the OP wants to exclude them.

Comment: Try again - it is syntactic sugar for a DERIVED table and it is used as a join. It is NOT a subquery in the true sense. It is odd that you write this here but not for your use of IN - how exactly is that NOT in fact a subquery?

Comment: A derived table is a form of sub-query :) but yes I am not claiming to have removed the sub-query in my answer.